# How to bundle Angular 2 component css?

Tags: css, angular, bundle

In my application for angular 1 I used to bundle all of the css in `library.css` and `application.css`. While this can be done with angular 2 the same way for ordinary css, there is a new feature that allows a "component css". As far as I can see Angular just downloads the css file and then processes it to add some id's to not interfere with each other.

Now if I just bundle all of these css'es Angular just won't be able to find them. Is it possible at all to do bundling of component css? Perhaps a similar way to bundling HTML exists, where HTML is really put into .js as string?

Comment: You can put your css at global level. It is not compulsory to define css in component.

Comment: use Webpack to bundle html and css

Comment: or simple Gulp command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this with `webpack` and a special `angular2-template-loader` [plugin](https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader). This is the config from webpack 2:

```
module: {
   rules: [
   {
      test: /\.ts$/,
      use: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
   }
```

Basically what it does, it replaces `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` with inline `template` and `styles` and just stores them in a string as a separate "module".

> How does it work
>
> The angular2-template-loader searches for templateUrl and styleUrls
>   declarations inside of the Angular 2 Component metadata and replaces
>   the paths with the corresponding require statement. If keepUrl=true is
>   added to the loader's query string, templateUrl and styleUrls will not
>   be replaced by template and style respectively so you can use a loader
>   like file-loader.
>
> The generated require statements will be handled by the given loader
>   for .html and .js files.

P.S. The whole set up can be found in Anagular [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html).

Answer (score 0):

These are the combination of the loaders that does the trick if you have

**templateUrls**  and **styleUrls**

```js
 loaders: [{
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },

            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader',
                exclude: [root('src/index.html')]
            },


            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'to-string-loader!css-loader'
            }

        ],
```

and in the code

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: 'sub.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['app.component.css']

})

export class AppComponent {

}
```