# Where should .html, .css, etc. files for Typescript + Angular 2 + ASP.Net Core 1.0 be located?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, project-structure

Typescript tutorial to create ASP.Net Core application (with or without Angular 2) suggests that we create a folder Scripts and use gulp task to copy only the .js files to `wwwroot` folder, e.g. during the build.

Now that makes sense, but what do we do with all the .html, .css, etc. files that angular 2 can utilize. It seems that there are generally two way of doing it:

1. Adding them to `wwwroot` folder.

   - Benefits: no need to add gulp task for these static files
   - Drawbacks: we'll have to duplicate the folder structure and do operations of copy/rename/etc twice
2. Keeping them in the `Scripts` folder outside of `wwwroot` (then we'd better rename it to `Source` or something like that.

   - Benefits: no duplication, all in one place
   - Drawbacks: we'll have to copy them to `wwwroot` in gulp task

In case 2 `wwwroot` becomes like a `bin` folder for ordinary application.

Are there any official guidelines/advices on the topic (I was not able to find any) that I can use as a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally people use method 2, though most people (me included) call the folder "app" rather than "source" or "scripts" and copy them via gulp.

One reason for doing so is that we can exclude `wwwroot` folder from source control management. Another being that for production you want to bundle your files (both html, css and the resulting *.js files), so your `wwwroot` folder will contain different set of data, depending on if you are developing or deploying it.

And since it's content will change often (with each build/bundling) and it may generate fairly large and minified flies, its less suitable for source control anyways (minified/uglified/concated files are hard/difficult/impossible to create diffs for).

For angular in specific you want to keep the *.html, *.ts, *.js and *.css (only the ones related to components) in the same location/subfolder. Visual Studio will automatically group them together (i.e. `sample.component.html`, `sample.component.ts`,`sample.component.css` and `sample.component.js` will be grouped together and you can unfold them by pressing the little triangle next to the grouped name) and it works well for bundling as angular2 css/template can be made to use [component relative path](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html), if you use a module loader (recommended!).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I was thinking that way too, then our `wwwroot` becomes really analogue of `bin` folder that we never want in source control. As you mentioned the bundling which is a good idea to have, I was wondering if you can help with the bundling the css. It's described all over how to bundle html, but bundling css I cannot find at all (we can't use ordinary css file bundle, since angular needs to process them). Have made a separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283535/how-to-bundle-angular-2-component-css but did not get an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel gulp as a helpfull tool, so don't use it in my template(ng2+material+asp.net core).
but need to remember to run "npm start" to compile any ng2 changes before run "dotnet run".

here is my solution template you can try: https://github.com/Longfld/ASPNETCoreAngular2